# App height incorrect after upgrading to iOS9 & Xcode 7

Tags: ios, height, screen, ios9

I just upgraded my Xcode to version 7 which as you all know using iOS SDK 9.
For some reason I'm having problems with the size of the screen now, I'm getting some black spaces at the top and bottom of the screen.

Now I read the following post in Apple's web site : 
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/18351

So I tried all kind of things related to the launch screen (although that in iOS 8) I never used launch screen. So I tried to add a launch screen image - just a blank one, I also tried instead of using static launch screen to use a XIB screen that I created (which again is just blank) and then I'm getting a result where my screen is all small on the top left corner of the screen.

Did anyone face that issue ? It is very weird :/

Any help / guidance will be much appreciated !

Thank you !

---

Edit :
The screen as I see it without having the XIB as my launch screen : 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B87Vpzycaz_CVW9NMEdvVmNhV2M

The screen as I see it with the XIB as my launch screen:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B87Vpzycaz_CemxLN2VCNEtTc0U

Comment: What size of black space? Like a mm, cm, or in?

Comment: Emm that is a very good question - I'm not even sure how I can measure it :/ You can see the screenshots in here https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B87Vpzycaz_CVW9NMEdvVmNhV2M

Comment: and the result I'm getting after I added the XIB screen is the following : https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B87Vpzycaz_CemxLN2VCNEtTc0U

Comment: OK seems like the issue was resolved when I added a launch image for iPhone 5 size. I'll be honest and say that I'm not 100% sure why it solved the problem but it did.... thanks for your help !